# Graph visualization

Tags: c#, java, graph

I have to visualize an input as a graph. My input will be in any of the below formats. (RDF, adjacency list, adjacency matrix). I am not concerned with the structure of the input now. I have to visually represent the input in the form of a graph. For example, if my RDF query is as below.

```
<sachin Tendulkar, plays, cricket>
```

I have to represent the above in a graph format. My input will not be constant and it will vary from time to time. So, I don't want to use some graph generation tool. I have to get the input from the user and based on his input, I have to generate the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You say you don't want to use "some graph generation tool", but it seems to me that the simplest approach would be to get a good tool, or graph library, and then normalise your input to whatever format the tool/library expects.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to Plot[sachin Tendulkar, plays, cricket] in a program like Mathematica the output is:

[image]

You will need some numeric data to generate Graphs.

Comment: The question is about graphs as-in vertices connected by edges, not histograms or line graphs.

Comment: All I see is alpha-numeric data.

Comment: But adjacency-lists and adjacency-matrices are data structures for representing vertex/edge type graphs.  I haven't seen his example syntax before, but I imagine it's intended to represent two vertices - `Sachin Tendulkar` and `Cricket` - connected by a directed edge labelled `plays`